# Uploadify repeating "SWF DEBUG: ExternalInterface reinitialized"

Tags: php, jquery, flash, uploadify

I am using Uploadify and after I select an image nothing happens. I looked at the debug console and it keeps repeating the line SWF DEBUG: ExternalInterface reinitialized

What causes this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same error, you should check out your flash logs. Just install the debugger version and follow the manual here: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/configure-debugger-version-flash-player.html

For me it was a crossdomain issue, where one domain was on HTTP and the other HTTPS.